# Firing events on many DOM elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I was wondering if it is possible to fire many events (not only one element with one type of event) at the same time in JavaScript on different DOM elements ("li" , "a" , " input", etc..) , I'm using the function `fireEvent(element , event)` to do the job with only one element and only one kind of event (`onchange` for example):

```
function fireEvent(element,event) {
   if (document.createEvent) {
   // dispatch for firefox + others
   var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
   evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
   return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
   } else {
   // dispatch for IE
   var evt = document.createEventObject();
   return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
}
}
```

How can use this function to fire many events on many DOM elements?

Comment: I want to get the results of all the event handlers that are in a webpage

Comment: I can think of no use case for this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with jQuery.

```
$("elements").action1().action2()
```

Having queue:false will trigger all the actions at the same moment.

Dunno if I understood your requirement correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/t8mr7/1/
All the 4 actions being executed at the same event trigger.

Comment: This is incorrect. Javascript executes linearly, so only one function can be executing at any given time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t8mr7/1/ I just wrote this fiddle. all the four actions take at the same instant of the event trigger.

Comment: What you've demonstrated is jQuery magic that uses a queuing system of sorts to "get around" Javascript's linearity. Nonetheless, Javascript is linear at base level.

Comment: Suppose i have something like :
<input type="text" onlick="alert('i was clicked')" id="test">
<li type="text" onchange="alert('i was clicked2')" id="test">
how can i fire the two events on the 2 elements input and li with Jquery?